# Starting weblogic with startWebLogic.cmd

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I am using WLST script to create a domain in Weblogic 10.3.4. Then starting the Admin Server and deploying a war file.All in the script.

In this WLST I am also updating the setDomainEnv.cmd file to add certian jars at the beginning of the classpath. This setDomainEnv.cmd will be called when we start the domain with startWebLogic.cmd.

But in the script when i start the server using the startServer command, it does not call the startWebLogic.cmd and therefore my updated setDomainEnv.cmd  is not called.
As a result, although everything else works just fine (Like Domain creation, war deployment) my application fails as the necessary jars are not loaded.
To be specific i want to append javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar and com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201105051105.jar in the classpath.

Any suggestions as to how can i call startWebLogic.cmd from WLST. 
Also if we can call startWebLogic.cmd from an ant task or Maven will also do.

Edit

My weblogic.xml looks like the below

```
      <container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>javax.el.*</package-name>
  <package-name>com.sun.el.*</package-name>
   <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
   <package-name>javax.persistence.criteria.*</package-name>
   <package-name>javax.persistence.metamodel.*</package-name>
   <package-name>javax.persistence.spi.*</package-name>  
   <package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.*</package-name>      
   <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>      
  </prefer-application-packages>          
 </container-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can choose one of the below approach

1 - Put all your jars in %DOMAIN_HOME%/lib folder and they will be added to the classpath during server start , this way you need not have to modify setDomainEnv.cmd. The catch here is if you read readme.txt under %DOMAIN_HOME%/lib you would see that these jars are added at the end of the classpath, so if you want all of these jars to be at the start of the classpath then this is not a good solution.

2 - One way of starting the servers which go through startWebLogic.cmd is using nodemanager
   - Of course for this approach you would need nodemanger to be configured, registered with the domain and started before starting your domain
   - use nmConnect and issue nmStart
   - Refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21050/starting_nodemgr.htm#NODEM209 for more details on this

In Future : Note that having classpath set in the setDomainEnv may work fine if server is always started using started using startWebLogic.cmd but if there will be any usecase that the server can be started from AdminConsole as well, then you need to set the classpath at : Login to AdminConsole–>Environments—.Servers—>YourManagedServer—>Configuration (TAB)—>ServerStart (SubTab) -> Classpath (text area)

Comment: I had already tried Point 1 and as you mentioned it adds the entries at the end of the classpath so it did not serve my purpose.Regarding Nodemanager, i tried setting it up and faced some issues.Left it there.May be i will give it a shot again. May i ask another question. I am preety sure that my application will be the only app running in the domain. So is it ok that i deply it in the Admin server rather than create a managed server?

Comment: Generally in production having applications deployed on the AdminServer is not recommended as it should be used only for administration purposes, but weblogic doesn't enforce this, so I guess you can deploy your application on the AdminServer itself. Reg. the serverstart : I think going ahead with the nodemanager approach is better. Could you tell what issues you faced while configuring NM?

Comment: I have added a seperate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529628/does-node-manager-through-wlst-in-weblogic-10-3-4-call-startweblogic-cmd) with the issue I am facing with NodeManager. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I wont question why you need these jars deployed, but the way to do this in Weblogic is to deploy them as a Shared Library.  You can probably do this with WLST or the Deployer in a script.  Modifying the cmd files seems like a hack to me.

Comment: The reason I am doing it this way is that Weblogic has its own version of EL jars which is different from the ones i need. When we start weblogic, it will load its own version of EL jars.I also tried just putting these jars in the lib folder of the Domain, but that also did not work

Comment: Do you think using Shared library, i will be able to override what weblogic has already loaded. I can give it a shot maybe

Comment: Another approach is to put your jar is WEB-INF/lib the use the prefer-web-inf-classes element.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1082452  prefer-web-inf-classes example

Comment: I had already tried prefer-web-inf-classes but there is a different issue with it. MY app needs JPA 2.0 where as weblogic 10.3.4 loads JPA 1.0 by default. If i use prefer-web-inf-classes JPA 1.0 gets loaded by weblogic and this creates a problrm. I am instead using <prefer-application-packages> to load JPA 2.0 packages. But sadly the same approach is not working for EL jars

Comment: I have updated the question with my weblogic.xml. The packages javax.persistence.* and org.eclipse.persistence.* are working fine as expected. But javax.el.* and com.sun.el.* are not working as expected. I get "Caused by: com.sun.el.parser.ParseException:" excpetion. I think the weblogic's glassfish.el_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar is being used