# Does Node Manager through WLST in Weblogic 10.3.4 call startWeblogic.cmd

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am using weblogic 10.3.4 and have a WLST script which does the following
1. Creates a Domain
2. Create JDBC
3. Start NodeManager
4. Connect to Nodemanager
5. And Deploy my App

Below are the relevant sections of my script

```
      templatehome = domainhome + "/wlserver/common/templates/domains/wls.jar"
      readTemplate(templatehome)
      create('MyDomain', 'Domain')
      cd('/Security/MyDomain/User/weblogic')
      cmo.setName(domainuserid)
      cmo.setUserPassword(domainpwd)    
      writeDomain(domainlocation + '/'+ domainname)
      ---Some other code related to JDBC
      closeTemplate()
      ---- Updating setDomainEnv.cmd
        f = open(domainlocation+ '/' + domainname +'/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd', "a+")
f.write("set CLASSPATH=%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar;%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201105051105-com.sun.el_2.2.0.v201105051105.jar;%CLASSPATH%")
f.close()


      startNodeManager()
      nmConnect(domainuserid, domainpwd, 'localhost', '5556', 'MyDomain','D:/MyLoc/Tools/Weblogic/user_projects/domains/MyDomain')
      nmStart('AdminServer')
       connect()
      deploy('myapp','my-war-location')
```

Please note that i am updating the SetDomainEnv.cmd in the WLST code itself.

When i run this script the domain gets created, the node manager gets started and the application gets deployed.
But the Server start does not happen through startWEblogic.cmd and my updated SetDomainEnv.cmd is not called.
So the question is does NodeManager use startWEblogic.cmd to start a Server?
If yes then why is it not happening in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check StartScriptEnabled and StartScriptName properties in nodemanager.properties (ex: wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager/nodemanager.properties)

StartScriptEnabled should be set to true and StartScriptName should be set to startWebLogic.cmd. By default these values are set, if they are not then please set them and restart nodemanager for the changes to take effect.

If the above fix doesn't work, then please update the question with the nodemanager.log content.

Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21050/java_nodemgr.htm#i1068413

Comment: Thanks. Yes this fixed the proble. I am now using the below command in my WLST "startNodeManager(NodeManagerHome=nodemanagerhome, StartScriptEnabled='true')". But there is another issue. This works fine in Windows. But the same set of commands(with the updated startNodeManager) in Linux gives a message "Not Connected to Node Manager". Any idea why? Do we have to start the nodeManager Manually in linux (by using xinetd)?

Comment: I think nmConnect did not go through successfully. Did you change the domainDir parameter's value? Debug : Also to confirm if startNodeManager starts the nodemanager in your environment or not you can just execute that single command in wlst prompt and also issue nmConnect to see if its going through successfully.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a typo from my side.